# Protecting apiResource in api.php Laravel + Jetstream + Inertia.js

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-middleware, laravel-jetstream, inertiajs, laravel-api

How can I recreate this? I am new to Laravel, and I have set up a `Route::apiResourcepost` data from my vue pages to my controller. I know that I need to protect the API resource and am trying to build an understanding as to how. In api.php, the following works:

```
Route::apiResource('name', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyController');
```

But when I try to protect the route with middleware like so:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->apiResource('name', 'App\Http\Controllers\MyController');
```

I get status 401 unauthorized back, and the response is:

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

Any feedback as to what I am doing wrong/should be doing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are working with the **auth:api** middleware, you have to pass a **Bearer Token** for Authentication in your headers.

[Check out this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication)